# "China's history" vs "Chinese history"

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between using "**China's history**" and "**Chinese history**"?

Comment: To summarize the excellent but necessarily complicated answers below, _usually none but..._ Is there any special context or confusion that this came up in? If you edit the question now, it might make the answers no longer match. You can post more details here in the comments, though, and we can give you more specific feedback.

Comment: Note also that the answers below don't get into the issue of 'China' at all. In some modern contexts, _China's history_ can sometimes be talking specifically about the history of the People's Republic of China. _Chinese history_ will always be more general than that... although in other contexts it might _also_ be talking about legal nationality instead of general ethnicity or cultural identity. China's a big concept and discussion of it can get mafan and fuzade really quickly.

Comment: What about "the history of China?"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**"China's history" is strictly history of / about China**, mainly as a nation. It's equivalent to "History of China". If it's about certain aspects of China, we could say "History of China's religions", "History of China's emperors", "History of China's food", etc. In that way, China is the main focus and history is the aspect of China we're talking about.

**But "Chinese history" can also mean:**

- history of the Chinese people and their culture (both in China and in other countries)
- history written in the Chinese language
- history written by Chinese scholars
- history written according to Chinese historiography (the way China's native scholars construct historical narratives)
- history about *other* countries but from a Chinese perspective (for example, "a Chinese history of the United States")
- etc.

Thus in "Chinese history", history is the main focus and Chinese (in all its different meanings) is the aspect of history we're talking about.

Comment: It's probably not helpful to use the grammatical term _modifier_ so badly here on an ELL forum. In both _China's history_ and _history of China_, history is the main noun and the other term is the modifier. You're just talking about semantic emphasis, focus, &c. which is a separate concept from grammatical modification.

Comment: Your main points are entirely valid but, since you went out of your way to bold the wrong and misleading bits, it's probably better if you rephrase them more carefully when you have time.

Comment: Feel free to edit it as you see fit.  I'm not that well versed in linguistics / grammatical terminologies.

Comment: @lly Sounds much better, thank you!

Comment: Jeez, I had almost forgotten that there are _nice_ people on the internet too. Thanks for making my day =) and hope yours is just as good.

Comment: Yes, I would generally understand "China's history," with no other context, to refer to the polity formed in 1949. That said, it's pretty easy to imagine a context where it refers to history farther back. I don't think there's really much of a difference worth stressing over.

Answer (score 10):

Without additional context, I believe these would differ as follows:

- "*Chinese history*" would generally be taken to mean the history written by Chinese historians and taught in Chinese schools, in the manner of Chinese culture.
- "*China's history*" would generally be taken to mean any history involving China, the history of China as a country (from any perspective), or the country's 'track-record' from the perspective of other nations.

Different contexts may affect the meaning. For example "*China's history books*" would pretty much mean the same as "*Chinese history books*", as one is the books belonging to China and the other is booked written in the Chinese language.

For comparison you might consider the difference in meaning between "Chinese food" and "China's food". The former would be foods that are *styled* by Chinese culture no matter where in the world it is produced or eaten, whereas the latter could be what is observedly owned by the country - what they actually produce, eat or export themselves.

Comment: I know you're trying to clarify but fwiw the example you give in your last paragraph _directly contradicts_ the way you're using the same terms in your lead.

Comment: The 2nd paragraph is simply wrong. _China's history books_ would be books on history made or owned by China. _Chinese history books_ are books about Chinese history or about history from a Chinese perspective. Neither refers to history written in any Chinese language at all and they aren't 'pretty much the same' at all.

Comment: @lly "Chinese history books" can mean what you say but they definitely also simply can mean that they are written in a Chinese language

Comment: @lly You're being hypercritical. My overall point is to show that they *are* different. I've stated very clearly in my answer that my initial definitions are without context and I've demonstrated that context can change the meaning. You can offer as many alternative meanings as you like - it doesn't make my answer wrong, and I don't believe it would be helpful to expand my answer to include them. Possible contexts would not be an exhaustive list.

Comment: I was taught a course called "European History" at school and it was most definitely the history of (continental) Europe from a British perspective. So I'm a bit doubtful about this answer.

Comment: @lvo At a grammatical semantic level sure. In the actual world, no, that concept wouldn't be expressed that way at all. You'd _expect_ the history books of the Chinese to be written in their own language, but the words themselves don't have anything to do with the language and if that was the point someone was trying to make they'd express it differently.

Comment: @Astralbee Nope. Normal amount of critical. That said, the comments are here to suggest improvements or provide context. You've chosen not to improve and my objections are noted. People can handle it however they like. Worth noting the guy who _did_ incorporate my feedback went from 0 or 1 to ranked way ahead of you now though.

Answer (score 8):

Colloquially there can be a difference between those two forms in specific instances like this.

"China" refers to a nation defined by a geographical landmass and a political boundary. Therefore "China's history" can (if used this way by the author) refer to the history of the nation.

"Chinese" refers to a people: a cultural or ethnic grouping. Therefore "Chinese history" can refer to the *people,* but not necessarily the *nation.*

Can they be synonymous? Absolutely, and I believe there's an excellent argument to say they are. However, they can also be used distinctly to emphasize the intent of an article.

If the article is discussing the behavior or culture of the Chinese people, then it would be more appropriate to use the phrase "Chinese history." Examples could include the history of Chinese immigrants in other countries or the history of Chinese fashion. In context, the article would be discussing something that *is Chinese,* but not necessarily something that happened *in China.*

Compare this to an article discussing *what happened when in China.* For example, articles discussing the changes in China's political structures over the years, or the spread of Daoism and its effects on national identity, or the effects of government policy on the environment in the Jiangsu province, would all be more appropriately identified as "China's history."

However, there is one more point worth making. From the perspective of a native English speaker in the western United States, I would easily (perhaps lazily) assume "Chinese history" to be synonymous with "China's history." However, I would not as easily assume "China's history" to be synonymous with "Chinese history." From our point of view, it's easy to distinguish the history of a nation from the history its people, but it's not as easy to distinguish the history of a people from the history of their nation.

As I think about it, this is an odd behavior — but I perceive that it is a distinct and predictable behavior. I offer as an example, "American history" and "United States history" or the "history of the United States of America." There is a distinct colloquial difference between those two, but using "American history" as a synonym for the "history of the United States of America" would be more frequent than assuming the "history of the United States of America" is a synonym for "American history." Linguist will likely disagree, but I'm willing to wager if I ask a class of 12th-grade high school students to explain the difference between the two, they can explain it with reasonable consistency.

Comment: Adding to this, ‘Chinese history’ could also be the history of the Chinese languages, or history _in_ one of the Chinese languages, or even history as portrayed by the Chinese (either history as their historians recount it, or history as their government insists it to be).

Comment: For the ELLs taking notes, at least some of the senses discussed by Mr Hemmelgarn would more clearly be discussed as _Chinese historiography_. That said, sure, language isn't always clear and using _history_ to mean _historiography_ happens constantly.